# Have two Stack Exchange communities ever been merged after graduating?

Tags: discussion

The question that came to my mind is: did it happen in the Stack Exchange history that two independent communities were merged together (e.g., due to an overlap of topics or members being involved in both communities)?

If so, was the merge ultimately successful?

Comment: Just a guess but **No**. The only reason to merge would be that the sites were to similar and that would be caught in Area 51

Comment: Not the graduated communities, but the [Sports beta](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/27135/sports) was merged with many proposals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has not happened with graduated sites.

The one post-Area 51 merge than I know of is the merge of Social Sound Design with the Audio part of Audio Video Production. This merge resulted in the current [Sound Design](https://sound.stackexchange.com/) site and was widely considered a bad move (ref [4] below).

1. [The Audio Merge With Sound Design SE Is Now Underway](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/q/353)
2. [The Sound SE community is about to get much bigger!](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/q/36)
3. [Social Sound Design / Audio-Video Production Merge Post Mortem](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/q/105)
4. [Where do we go from here? Take the survey!](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1324)

Also, some Area 51 proposals got merged prior to site launch, such as  [Sports](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/27135/sports) (pointed out by Arulkumar) and [Cognitive Sciences](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2149/cognitive-sciences).

Comment: The 4th reference is fascinating because it shows just how fragile a community can be.