# Any successful mergers of Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

Have there been any successful mergers?

This is some [basic Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342646/merging-technical-sites-with-stack-overflow) about merging sites, but I'm looking for more information.

Comment: This is somewhat of a duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130342/323179

Comment: Technical Communication merged with Writing as the former's private beta was ending.

Comment: How do you define *"successful"*? The *first* astronomy site was merged into *[Physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physics)*, losing *any* chance to cover *observational* astronomy.

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q that is a good example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if they are technically called merges, but sometimes, early in their lifecycle, sites with not enough activity had their content mass-migrated to other sites. Some cases where this happened:

- [Game of Go](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11942/game-of-go), to Board & Card Games: [Hey! Where did all the Go questions come from? And why aren't there any gorrible puns in this title?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/636/12315)
- [Guitars](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6320/guitars), to Music: Practice & Theory: [The Guitars SE site has been folded in to this site](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/170/19800)
- [Technical Communication](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101439/technical-communication), to Writing: [Let's migrate content from Technical Communication here](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1473/14426) (thanks @Sonic)

Comment: audio.se and video.se went into avp.se, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295791/158100

Comment: Thanks @rene. I'm now in doubt whether to expand this answer, or merge (pun intended) it with the one you linked to...

Comment: @rene ...and were split apart again when Social Sound Design was migrated in from Stack Exchange 1.0.

Comment: I vaguely recall Running being merged into Sports as well.